# How to delay setting value of @State variable in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, datepicker

I want to create an application with a date picker. The initial value of the date picker (`startDate`) requires some computation performed in another class. (Let's say for example that this date is initially set to a customer's enrolment date in a service, which is retrieved from a database.) The user can leave that date as-is, or select a new date using the date picker.

I haven't been able to find a way of setting this initial value. The following simplified code illustrates the issue. The date picker shows the initial value of today's date rather than the desired date (here, `Date.distantPast`.) The date picker otherwise works fine.

Things I've tried:

- If I set the value in the `init` clause (as shown below), it is ignored (no error reported, but the value is not written to `startDate` variable).
- Trying to set the value of `startDate` inline with its declaration gives a compile-time error message ("Cannot use instance member 'db' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available".)
- Wrapping the DataPicker in an if-statement so it won't not be displayed until the `startDate` has been computed makes no difference.

Is there any way to defer the setting of the initial date selection in a date picker until it can be computed?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    private let db = DB()
    @State private var startDate = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        DatePicker("Start Date",
                   selection: $startDate,
                   displayedComponents: [.date])
    }
    
    init() {
        startDate = db.theDate
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

class DB {
    var theDate: Date
    
    init() {
        theDate = Date.distantPast
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a ViewModel to match your view. In the ViewModel you have more possibilities. For example, you can easily initialise `date` in the Init.

This would look something like this:

```swift
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    private let db = DB()
    
    @Published var date: Date
    
    init() {
        date = db.theDate
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        DatePicker("Start Date",
                   selection: $viewModel.date,
                   displayedComponents: [.date])
    }
}
```

Make sure that the ViewModel is an `ObservableObject` and that properties that can change use the property wrapper `@Published`.

If your app no longer needs to support iOS 13, you can also use `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservedObject`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Johannes. This worked perfectly. I apologize that I don't have enough reputation for my upvote to show.